# Why match object is borrowed in rust?

Tags: rust

The code case is from rustlings 'quiz2.rs'. I known command in ‘for(string,command)’ is borrowed from vector iterator. The command is borrowed, but why the 'n' Append(n) is also borrowed?

```rust
    pub fn transformer(input: Vec<(String, Command)>) -> Vec<String> {
        // TODO: Complete the output declaration!
        let mut output: Vec<String> = vec![];
        for (string, command) in input.iter() {
            // TODO: Complete the function body. You can do it!
            match command {
                Command::Uppercase => output.push(string.to_uppercase()),
                Command::Trim => output.push(string.trim().to_string()),
                Command::Append(n) => {
                    let can_mv_str = string.to_string() + &"bar".repeat(*n);
                    output.push(can_mv_str);
                }
            }
        }
        output
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `Vec::iter()` returns an iterator over *references* to the elements of the vector, that is, `&(String, Command)`.

Then, whenever you write a pattern for some specific structure, like the 2-element tuple `(string, command)` in the `for` loop, but the input is a *reference* to that structure, Rust matches "through" the reference and automatically gives you *references to the elements* (because it's not possible in general to *not* get references, since not every type is `Copy`).

So, the type of `command` is `&Command`. Then the same thing happens to the `match command {` and every variable binding in the `match`'s pattern (that is, `n`) will be a reference too.

If you want to avoid this, what you have to do is *explicitly write out matching against the references*:

```rust
match command {
    ...
    &Command::Append(n) => {
        let can_mv_str = string.to_string() + &"bar".repeat(n);
        output.push(can_mv_str);
    }
}
```

Or, you can dereference the input to the `match` (this won't necessarily try to move out of the reference — as long as you don't bind any non-`Copy` values):

```rust
match *command {
    ...
    Command::Append(n) => {
        let can_mv_str = string.to_string() + &"bar".repeat(n);
        output.push(can_mv_str);
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to *completely avoid the magic* and write out a program that is doing the whole thing explicitly, you also need to adjust the `for` pattern:

```rust
for &(ref string, ref command) in input.iter() {
```

The `ref` means "please don't try to *move* this value out of what I'm matching; just give me a reference to it. It's rarely seen in modern Rust because the automatic matching behavior I'm talking about makes it mostly unnecessary. This feature of Rust is called “match ergonomics”, because it saves you from writing a lot of `&` and `ref` all the time. But, as you've seen, it can lead to surprising behavior, and the old explicit style also lets you avoid dealing with needless references to `Copy` types like integers.

If you'd like to try writing Rust without ever using match ergonomics, to understand “what's really going on”, you can enable [a Clippy *restriction lint*](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#pattern_type_mismatch) to mark any places where the pattern doesn't actually fit the type of what it's matching:

```rust
#[warn(clippy::pattern_type_mismatch)]
```

and run `cargo clippy` to see the new warnings. You'll probably find that there's quite a lot of patterns that are implicitly working on references!

Answer (score 2):

This is because of [RFC 2005](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). Before that, there used to be special syntax of `ref` and `ref mut` when you wanted to take a reference to an inner field in match.

What happens here is that your `command` is an `&Command`. You match on it but the arms are all `Command`. So `command` gets de-referenced automatically. But then, in `Command::Append` you take ownership of the inner `n`. This cannot happen as your `command` was a reference. So rust gives you a reference to `n`.

You can fix this in multiple ways. The easiest is to dereference the `n` yourself, like so:

```rust
match command {
    Command::Append(&n) => ..., // n is owned here
    ...
}
```

This works when `n` is `Copy`. You can also do a `let n = n.clone()` in the match body itself if `n` is not `Copy` but is `Clone`.

You can also take ownership of `command`, like so:

```rust
match *command { // if Command is Copy
   Command::Append(n) => ..., // n is owned here
   ...
}

// OR

match command.clone() { // if Command is Clone
   Command::Append(n) => ..., // n is owned here
   ...
}
```

If you cannot do any of the above, then you will need to work with the reference itself or maybe change your iterator from `input.iter()` to `input.into_iter()` to get an owned `Command` from the start.